# Помимо художественной гимнастики(,) девочка

Tags: пунктуация

> Помимо художественной гимнастики(,) девочка увлекается актёрским
> мастерством (обучалась этому и снималась в сериалах), играет на
> фортепиано и гитаре, а также хорошо рисует.

Из "Грамоты" (https://clck.ru/bd7f9) следует, что можно не ставить запятую! Но как-то... не хватает её, что ли! Ставить или не ставить? Если не поставить, то ошибки не будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае обособление *обязательно*, поскольку "помимо" находится в абсолютном начале предложения (см. [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg78.php)).

Comment: А как же пример из "Грамоты" тогда? Вот этот: Категория эта кажется нам ее собственным, а не нашим, состояньем. Помимо этого состоянья всё на свете названо. Б. Пастернак, Охранная грамота. ( https://clck.ru/bd7f9 )

Comment: @Катперкат правила со временем уточняются. Тем более такие неустойчивые, как пунктуация вокруг оборотов со значением исключения, включения и замещения. Если не ошибаюсь, у Розенталя обязательности, указанной мной, ещё нет. А в лопатинском, более современном, справочнике — уже есть.

Comment: Т.е. "Грамота" устарела в этом месте?

Comment: @Катперкат я полагаю, что да. Тем не менее справочник Лопатина хоть и рекомендуется РАН (как более современный и отражающий сложившуюся пунктуацию), но он не обязателен. То есть если что-то написано по Розенталю, а не по Лопатину, то это не может считаться ошибкой. На данный момент русская орфография и пунктуация находится вот в таком несколько подвешенном состоянии.

Comment: Розенталь: Обособляются факультативно (в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения оборота, близости к основной части предложения и т. д.) имена существительные с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями кроме, вместо, помимо, сверх, за исключением, наряду с и др. (условно называемые дополнениями) со значением включения, исключения, замещения, т. е. ограничительным или расширительным значением.

Comment: Ссылка на Розенталя: https://clck.ru/h7iuB